# Can I create a virtual table in Dax to calculate account balance for products with different expiry dates?

Tags: join, powerbi, dax, virtual-table

I have product A, B, C. They each have opening balance amount at 1/11/2023 ,say 3000, 7000 and 11000 for A,B,C respectively. They each have expiry dates, say A, B and C expires on 11/11/2023, 5/11/2023 and 30/11/2023 respectively. The opening balance needs to be calculated each month until the expiry dates for the product, i.e. from 1/11 to 5/11, the total opening balance will be 21000 (for all the 3 products) and from 6/11 to 11/11, the total opening balance will be 14000 (3000+11000 for A and C as B has expired) and from 12 to 30/11, the total opening balance will be 11000 (for C only) as both A and B have expired. Is there a way to create a single measure through creation of virtual table or others to achieve this outcome. I tried the following codes but it didn't work:

Please find below the link to the sample PBI report. Appreciate some experts can help with the dax!! Thank you in advance!

[sample PBI report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sOjtS1whtMUIGd6UPQEC4bDDihiG-gYt/view)

**Opening balance**

| Date ID | Account Code | Product Code | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2023 | 1001 | A | 1000 |
| 01/11/2023 | 1002 | A | 2000 |
| 01/11/2023 | 1001 | B | 3000 |
| 01/11/2023 | 1002 | B | 4000 |
| 01/11/2023 | 1001 | C | 5000 |
| 01/11/2023 | 1002 | C | 6000 |

**Expiry date**

| Product Code | Expiry Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 11/11/2023 |
| B | 05/11/2023 |
| C | 30/11/2023 |

**Desired output**

| Date ID | A | B | C | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/11/2023 | 3000 | 7000 | 11000 | 21000 |
| 02/11/2023 | 3000 | 7000 | 11000 | 21000 |
| 03/11/2023 | 3000 | 7000 | 11000 | 21000 |
| 04/11/2023 | 3000 | 7000 | 11000 | 21000 |
| 05/11/2023 | 3000 | 7000 | 11000 | 21000 |
| 06/11/2023 | 3000 | 0 | 11000 | 14000 |
| 07/11/2023 | 3000 | 0 | 11000 | 14000 |
| 08/11/2023 | 3000 | 0 | 11000 | 14000 |
| 09/11/2023 | 3000 | 0 | 11000 | 14000 |
| 10/11/2023 | 3000 | 0 | 11000 | 14000 |
| 11/11/2023 | 3000 | 0 | 11000 | 14000 |
| 12/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 13/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 14/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 15/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 16/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 17/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 18/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 19/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 20/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 21/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 22/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 23/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 24/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 25/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 26/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 27/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 28/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 29/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |
| 30/11/2023 | 0 | 0 | 11000 | 11000 |

I tried the following codes but it didn't work:

```
Calculated opening balance test = 
  var latestdate = min(Dim_Date[Date ID])
  var latestexpirydate = min(Dim_Expiry_Date[Expiry Date])
  var datetable = filter(
    CROSSJOIN(all(Dim_Date),Dim_Expiry_Date), 
    latestdate<=latestexpirydate
  )
  return
    sumx(datetable, sum(Fact_Account_Opening_Balance[Amount]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Opening Balance =
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT(Dim_Product[Product Code]),
    (
      var sDate = MAX(Dim_Date[Date ID])
      var eDate = CALCULATE(MAX(Dim_Expiry_Date[Expiry Date]))
      var firstAvailableOpeningBalance = 
        TOPN( 1, 
          CALCULATETABLE(
            Fact_Account_Opening_Balance,
            REMOVEFILTERS(Dim_Date[Date ID]),
            Fact_Account_Opening_Balance[Date ID] <= sDate &&
            (ISBLANK(eDate) || sDate <= eDate)
          ),
          [Date ID], DESC
        )
      var result = SUMX(firstAvailableOpeningBalance, Fact_Account_Opening_Balance[Amount])
      return COALESCE(result, 0)
    )
  )
```

Notes:

- `SUMX(DISTINCT(Dim_Product[Product Code]), ... )`
  Perform the calculation for each Product Code - this is needed for Total columns.
- `firstAvailableOpeningBalance`
  Get's the first previous available balance available via `TOPN`.

Comment: How did this go? Any follow-up? Otherwise please help Accept the answer for the benefit of all.